# iOS Spritekit intersectsnode does not work for SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skshapenode

I am using the iOS SpriteKit Game Swift template on iOS8.3. I am trying to use the function `func intersectsNode(_ node: SKNode) -> Bool` to detect overlap of two circles created as SKShapeNodes. Turns out the function does not detect the intersection if its SKShapeNodes. But on further troubleshooting, it turns out the function works if I use the default Spaceship sprite of the template. Here is the code which works:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")

         sprite.xScale = 0.3
         sprite.yScale = 0.3
         sprite.position = location

        self.circles.append(sprite)

        self.addChild(sprite)

        if circles.count == 1 {
            println("One circle")
        } else {
            for var index = 0; index < circles.count-1; ++index {
                if sprite.intersectsNode(circles[index]) {
                    println(circles[index].frame)
                    println("Circle intersects another")
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When two sprites overlap in the above code the function returns YES and prints the intersection string. Here is the code which does NOT work:

```
   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        let sprite = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)

         sprite.position = location

        self.circles.append(sprite)

        self.addChild(sprite)

        if circles.count == 1 {
            println("One circle")
        } else {
            for var index = 0; index < circles.count-1; ++index {
                if sprite.intersectsNode(circles[index]) {
                    println(circles[index].frame)
                    println("Circle intersects another")
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see the code blocks are completely identical except in one case its an SKSpriteNode and the other case its SKShapeNode. I also printed the frames of the SKShapeNode Circles and I can see they have have valid frames. So I am puzzled by this as I would like to use SKShapeNodes in my code for now but I cannot use the intersectNode function as it does not work.

Comment: Check the bounding box of the node. The frame size and position. And btw, if you think the intersectNode is a smart function, it really isn't. It just checks if two frames share any points. If a node is intersecting the corner of a circle's bounding box, it'll be considered intersecting.

Comment: I am fine with the bounding box touching and the function returning with an YES. But nothing is happening for me. I have tried it with Circles and Rects. Looks like intersectNode just does not consider SKShapeNodes worth answering back and only prefers SKSpriteNodes. Unless I am doing something wrong. You can try my code in the default iOS Swift Game template. You just have to replace the `touchesBegan` method with the ones I have above.

Comment: Have you possibly tried containing the skshapenode as a skspritenode? Try adding the skshapenode as a child. If you ever need to access it and don't want to declare it as a variable, there's a useful name property

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for `intersectsNode` says this:

> The two nodes are considered to intersect if their frames intersect. The children of both nodes are ignored in this test.

Which means you won't get the result you want when using circles.

However, checking if two circles overlap is as easy as checking if the distance between their centers is less than the sum of their radiuses.

Comment: Circle or Square there is always an associated frame. If I print the frame I get proper values. But just for fun, I changed my SKShapeNode to a rect with the following `let sprite = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSizeMake(50.0, 50.0))` and still does not work. I understand I could do the calculation for checking the overlap but I wanted to use the intersectsNode method with other polygons too.